Global dimension of a ring and Ext functor
Let $R$ be a commutative ring. The global dimension of $R$ is defined as the supremum over all cohomological dimensions (or projective dimensions) of all $R$-modules.
I know that the $\operatorname{Ext}_R^i$ groups give an upper bound for the projective dimension, and à fortiori, on the global dimension. For instance if $\operatorname{Ext}_R^{d+1}(A,B) = 0$ for all $R$-modules B, then the projective dimension of $A$ is at most $d$.

Is it true that the global dimension of $R$ is the largest degree $d$ such that there is a non-trivial $\operatorname{Ext}_R^{d}$ group?

Thank you for any hint or reference.

It turns out that the answer is yes!
Claim: Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. The following statements are equivalent:
i) Every $R$-module has projective dimension at most $n$.
ii) Every finitely generated $R$-module has projective dimension at most $n$.
iii) Every $R$-module has injective dimension at most $n$.
iv) For all $R$-modules $M,N,$ we have $\operatorname{Ext}_R^{n+1}(M,N) = 0$.
Proof:
i)$\implies$ ii) is trivial.
ii)$\implies$ iii): Let $(I^{\bullet})$ be an injective resolution of $N$. We get an exact sequence
$$ 0\to N\to I^0\to\dots\to I^{n-1}\to I'\to 0 $$ where $I' = \operatorname{coker}(I^{n-2}\to I^{n-1})$. Thus $\operatorname{Ext}_R^{1}(M,I')= \operatorname{Ext}_R^{n+1}(M,N) = 0$ by ii) (since any projective resolution can be used to compute the $\operatorname{Ext}$). This means that any short exact sequence (in which $M=B/A$ is finitely generated) $$0\to A\to B \to M\to 0$$ will give an exact sequence $$ \operatorname{Hom}(B,I')\to \operatorname{Hom}(A,I') \to \operatorname{Ext}_R^1(M,I')=0, $$which says exactly that $I'$ is injective.
iii)$\implies$ iv): Use the injective resolution of $N$ above.
iv)$\implies$ i): Not difficult, I leave it for the reader.
Going back to my question, denote $gd(R)$ the global dimension, and denot $d$ the largest degree such that there exists a non-trivial $\operatorname{Ext}_R^d$ group. By the claim, there exists an $R$-module of projective dimension at least $d$, hence by definition of the global dimension, $gd(R)\ge d $. However, by definition of $d$, we know that part iv) is true in degree $d+1$, which implies i) in degree $d$, yielding $gd(R)\le d $, hence the equality.
